# Jython and Java nested class

Tags: java, class, nested, jython

I'm using Jython to write tests for a Java project.
It works well, but I can't figure how to get access to a 
java public nested class.

```
package mypackage;

public class NyClass {
    public class MyNestedClass {
         ...
    }
}
```

Does somebody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure by what you mean by access, but if you after creating instances of
the MyNestedClass it's no problem in jython.

In this case, since MyNestedClass is a non-static nested class every instance of it needs a 
reference to an instance of MyClass. To do this in jython:

```
import mypackage.MyClass
import mypackage.MyClass.MyNestedClass

outer = mypackage.MyClass()
inner = mypackage.MyClass.MyNestedClass(outer)
```